# Copy large amount of small files using robocopy from USB disk to SATA disk

Tags: usb, robocopy, multi-threading

Would specifying the /MT option in robocopy give me better or worse performance, when copying a large amount of smaller files (~10-150kB) from an USB attached drive to an internal SATA drive? Should I go all crazy and specify /MT:128?

Both drives are regular 5400k spinning hard disks.

Comment: You say USB attached drive, but you didn't mention the media type.  Is that flash, or a hard disk?  Why not just try a few options and see what happens?

Comment: It would take less time to test than it does to ask the question and then wait for answers.

Comment: Both sides are regular "spinning" hard disks

Comment: @John I know. But I was working on setting up the server, etc and knew that I will get to the copying in a couple of hours. So it seemed to be the reasonable thing to do, to quickly ask the question, keep working and hope for a quick answer. Sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly it totally depends. After a little testing I found out that the most important differentiator is the Operating System used to start the copy.

On XP/2003 the throughput went from okayish to horrible, at least on the setup I tested.

On a 2008 R2 the throughput went from okay to way faster, when I used the /MT:128. It seems as if the OS is smarter in planning disk access...

For me the copying was a one-time thing, so I won't investiagate any further. But the findings strongly suggest that there unfortunatelly is no general answer to that question.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would predict worse.  You want to minimize contention for IO if the limiting factor is seek/local access times.  Since you are not traversing a network, that will probably be the case.  (Unless you have a SSD as the source.)

Of course, test it out, but I would be surprised if you got noticeably better performance.  Let us know what you find.